# web browser - two logins at the same time

Tags: session, browser

I'm working on an instant chat and I need to test things out from two different client accounts. Project is running on localhost and when I logout in one tab it logs me out on the other one too.
Any way I could achieve this?

Comment: open a new browser session. Tabs within a window are considered part of the same session. You can use incognito mode, or just use a totally different browser (e.g. open one in Firefox and one in Chrome). P.S. This is about browser behaviour, none of this is related in any way to asp.net or visual studio. The same would apply to a web app written in _any_ language and which uses sessions.

Comment: @ADyson got it now. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not work in different tabs. Use different Browsers for testing.

Cheers,